# How to implement Reddit voting algorithm?

Tags: php, sql, algorithm, math

[image]

Assuming that I have the required database tables, is there any way to make a php or mysql version of this algorithm? A function that uses t, y and z as arguments, and return the rating.

Comment: You wouldn't need SQL unless you want to store results?

Comment: I don't get what's your problem. Is it `log` function or how to calculate x, y, z... ?

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov yes, the eqvivalent of log(10)z+(yt/2500) written in php

Comment: `function myCalc(y, z, t){ return log10(z) + y*t/2500; }` ?

Answer (score 2):

The reddit [source code](https://github.com/reddit/reddit) (currently down) is open for all to view, perhaps checking it out may be of some use.

Comment: What i linked is what i need from the source. I just want it as a php function.

Comment: why down-voting ? It's useful answer

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov probably because I wont write his code for him :)